# Laravel Vue cannot load env variables

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to disable the Vue Devtools in production so i want inside the app.js to check if the APP_ENV variable is equal to production.

What i have done so far:

Inside webpack.mix.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Inside app.js

```
console.log(process.env.APP_ENV)//Undefined

if (process.env.APP_ENV === 'production') {
    Vue.config.devtools = false;
    Vue.config.debug = false;
    Vue.config.silent = true; 
}
```

Enviroment Variable

```
APP_ENV=production
```

I read the documentantion about adding MIX_APP_ENV so i can inject the variable inside webpack but it didn't also work.

Folder Structure:

```
d-----        01-Feb-21  10:31 PM                app
d-----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM                bootstrap
d-----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM                config
d-----        30-Jan-21  10:26 PM                database
d-----        16-Apr-21  10:49 PM                node_modules
d-----        29-Jan-21   1:14 PM                public
d-----        29-Jan-21  12:22 PM                resources
d-----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM                routes
d-----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM                storage
d-----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM                tests
d-----        01-Feb-21   9:29 PM                vendor
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM            220 .editorconfig
-a----        16-Apr-21  10:45 PM            954 .env
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:14 PM            816 .env.example
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM            111 .gitattributes
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM            191 .gitignore
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM            181 .styleci.yml
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM           1686 artisan
-a----        01-Feb-21  10:41 PM           1793 composer.json
-a----        01-Feb-21  10:41 PM         282388 composer.lock
-a----        16-Apr-21  10:49 PM         531190 package-lock.json
-a----        16-Apr-21  10:49 PM           1103 package.json
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM           1202 phpunit.xml
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM           3780 README.md
-a----        29-Jan-21  12:12 PM            563 server.php
-a----        16-Apr-21  10:55 PM            578 webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: Have you rerun `npm run watch` after setting the `MIX_APP_ENV`? And in js it should still be `process.env.MIX_APP_ENV`?

Comment: Yes i have done that, i also used php artisan optimize to clear everything.

Comment: Can you share with us the project dir tree? Because Dotenv checks the application root dir and get that `.env` files, may be it is searching for a `.env` file from another dir, to check if a dir is a root you need to check if there is a `package.json` inside it.

Comment: I added the folder structure. @DaviMendesDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that you need to re-run `npm run watch` if it is already running, that was the actual issue.